# Fallback in a multilingual database design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, window-functions

I'm designing a multilingual database about products – how original ;)

This is the simplified design:

[image]

If I select data for 'de', is it empty (`NULL`):

```sql
select 
    p.id,
    p.price,
    pi.name,
    pi.description
from public.products p
inner join public.locales loc
on loc.lang = 'de'
left join public.products_i18n pi
on p.id = pi.id and pi.lang = loc.id
```

[image]

I would like to have a fallback on english when the required locale is not present:

```sql
select 
    p.id,
    p.price,
    coalesce(pi.name, pi_def.name),
    coalesce(pi.description, pi_def.description)
from public.products p
inner join public.locales loc
on loc.lang = 'de'
left join public.products_i18n pi
on p.id = pi.id and pi.lang = loc.id
left join public.products_i18n pi_def
on p.id = pi_def.id and pi_def.lang = '1' -- fallback on english
```

However, I receive two rows: 1 row with the correct fallback data (description is expected to be empty), and 1 empty row.

[image: screen from pgAdmin4]

Is it a display issue with pgAdmin or is my query wrong?

SQL fiddle available there:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/485be/1

Comment: I see only one row in your result?
Please add schema definition, sample data and expected results - and please don't use images. A SQL Fiddle would be great!

Comment: There is a blank row. I didn't know about SQL fiddle, I'll come back to you in a minute!

Comment: @NevilleKuyt please see my updated question :) It seems to returns only 1 row, however the display of pgAdmin is.. strange with that emptry row. Perhaps it is only a display issue.

Comment: Your second query work good what's your question?

Comment: My question depends on whether or not it is normal pgAdmin shows me a second (but empty) row, compare to the first query. Is it a display non-sense from pgAdmin, or is it due to my query that generates a second and empty row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to join to 2 copies of `public.products_i18n`.
Filter `public.locales` so that it returns only `'de'` and `'en'` and use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get the details for `'de'` or `'en'` if `'de'` does not exist:

```
select distinct p.id, p.price,
       first_value(pi.name) over (partition by p.id order by loc.lang = 'de' desc) "name",
       first_value(pi.description) over (partition by p.id order by loc.lang = 'de' desc) description
from public.products p
inner join public.products_i18n pi on p.id = pi.id 
inner join public.locales loc on loc.lang in ('de', 'en') and pi.lang = loc.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=317238c98e132c63b450ddee1dd927fd).

Comment: This should returns `Beer` but returns `Bier`. However I was not aware of the `first_value()` function so thank you I'll read more about that

Comment: @Binajmen correct, I already edited.

Comment: `order by loc.lang = 'de' desc` should be understood as "give a priority to 'de' before ordering by descending values"?

Comment: @Binajmen exactly.

Comment: I've checked the query analysis in pgAdmin. Clearly way better than mine ;)

Comment: It seems however this will not retrieve the description if the description is available in english only. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/013207/6

Comment: @Binajmen do you mean that you want the english description when there is no french description even if there is french name? So in the results you will have french name and english description?

Comment: @Binajmen check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a695b781698b826c0d50c1a34a1c6aa and if this is what you want I will edit.

Comment: Mmmh now you say it out loud, maybe it doesn't make sense to mix languages.. my bad! Thanks for the snippet anyway!